# nth child selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <table width="600px" id='testTable'>
        <tr class="red"><td>this</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr class="red"><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr class="red"><td>this</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr class="red"><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    </table>


.gray
{
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
.red
{
    color:Red;
}

    $(function () {
        $('#testTable tr.red:nth-child(odd)').addClass('gray');
       //this should select tr's with text=this, but its not happening
    });
```

i want to select all odds inside table which have class=red  , but its not happening. please help

Comment: I don't think the rows you identified with "this" are the odd ones.  The first one labeled "this" is odd, and the ones with value "1" are odd, and the second one labeled "this" is not odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nth-child(odd) selects the odd members of the element's *parent* not the odd members of the set returned by the selector.

You're looking for this:

```
$('#testTable tr.red').filter(':even').addClass('gray');
```

Edit: actually you want the even ones, i think. It's a 0-based index. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/utode)

Comment: yaa, it worked- thanx i was looking for this something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `.red` and `:nth-child(odd)` does not do what you think it does. Each of those two parts only applies to the `tr` element, not to each other. So it won't first find all red elements, then highlight alternate ones of those, it only selects rows where both "conditions" are true.

There is a solution in jQuery though - first select just the red elements, and use each:

```
$(function () {
    $('#testTable tr.red').each( function(i) {
        if ( i%2 == 1 )
            $(this).addClass('gray');
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work if you change `if ( i%2 == 1 )` to `if ( i%2 == 0 )` -- he's looking to change the rows with text: "this".

Comment: i was planning to do something like this but ghoppe's answer solved my problem

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you try something a little more long winded such as

```
$(function() {
    $('#testTable tr:nth-child(odd)').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('red')) { $(this).addClass('grey'); }
    });
});
```

This should do what your asking for

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. see his comment: "this should select tr's with text=this, but its not happening"

Comment: the last line states he wants all odds in the table that have a class of red, that's what this does ...

Though I should have looked closer at the table mark up.